# Shade outside of Unit Circle with fading color

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I wanted to shade the outside of my unit circle in my code below to get [this effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351600/how-to-shade-the-outside-of-a-region):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
% Axes:
\draw [-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node [above left]  {$\Re$};
\draw [-latex] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node [below right] {$\Im$};
\draw[dashed] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (-0.9,0) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (-0.5,0) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.75,0) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,0.3) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,-0.3) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Pole plot for $Q(z)$ in the $Z$ plane.}
\label{polezero1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid filling the inner circle with white by using the `even odd rule` to shade. This will ensure that any coloured background will show through. (Of course, if you want a white inner circle, you should *not* use this method!)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade [inner color=red, outer color=white, even odd rule] circle (1.5) circle (1);
  % Axes:
  \draw [-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node [above left]  {$\Re$};
  \draw [-latex] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node [below right] {$\Im$};
  \draw[dashed] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
  \node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (-0.9,0) {};
  \node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (-0.5,0) {};
  \node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.75,0) {};
  \node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,0.3) {};
  \node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,-0.3) {};
  \node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>even odd rule</code>]

Answer (score 4):

Like this? I'm not sure if you want the upper half shaded or the whole outer circle, if the latter case, then remove the `scope` (lines 11 and 14) and clip (line 12: `\path[clip] ..`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, > = latex]
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (-1.5,0) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\path [inner color=red, outer color=white] (0cm,0cm) circle(1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[dashed,fill=white] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

% Axes:
\draw [->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node [above left]  {$\Re$};
\draw [->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node [below right] {$\Im$};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (-0.9,0) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (-0.5,0) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.75,0) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,0.3) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,-0.3) {};
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Pole plot for $Q(z)$ in the $Z$ plane.}
\label{polezero1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]